# Preventing lag on touch events in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, touch, delay

I'm building a Phonegap-based Android/iOS app. The app is supposed to detect swipes from the user.

On Android, when detecting the gestures, the app consistently displays delay of approximately **200ms** before executing my code.

Reading around, I learned that this delay might be caused by how Android distinguishes swipes from normal taps. If you call `e.preventDefault()` before 200ms have elapsed since the touch, WebKit will let you handle it as a swipe.

**Question:**
Is there a way to completely remove this delay and force WebKit to assume the event is a swipe, thus removing the delay?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the delay is around 300ms and in this article [1], the reason why browser OEMs implemented this behaviour is given.
There is a library called fastclick [2] that you can use to prevent this.
Personally, I'm using polymer gestures which has a much broader scope but holistically solves the problem of detecting gestures *and* preventing the 300ms delay.

[1] http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

[2] https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

[3] https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures